# count exact 5 minutes from date

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I faced up with problem to calculate exact 5 minutes from time. Here the scenario, from the server response I get `dateTime` in format `YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss` after that I show up local timer on page which counts 5 minutes after that time. I do it with momentjs.

```js
var output = document.getElementById('out');

var fromCount = '2017-02-22 00:23:50';
var toMins = moment(fromCount).add(5, 'minutes');
var toMinsCount = setInterval(function(){
  var now = moment();
  var diff = moment(toMins - now).format('mm:ss');
  if(diff==='00:00'){
    clearInterval(toMinsCount);
    // something more here
    output.innerText = 'times up change fromCount data time';
  }
  if(now>toMins){
    clearInterval(toMinsCount);
    output.innerText = 'change fromCount data time';
  } else {
    output.innerText = diff;
  }
},1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>

<div id="out"></div>
```

Everything works nice BUT, sometimes when I add 5 minutes to date counter starts count from `5:13` or bit higher, it occurs when for example data from count = `'2017-02-22 00:30:50'` and now date = `'2017-02-22 00:30:15'`. So how can I avoid this problem and show local counter exact `5:00` minutes?

I need to count it from servers time because my counter depends on special event. And I should show for each user came to page same time from the moment server has catch. In local way each user will see it's own 5 min timer.

Comment: If you want your local counter to countdown 5 minutes according to local time, then why do you need to return a time from your server at all?

Comment: @bejado I edited my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here the solution that fits my needs.

```
function count5min(value) {
    $http.get('https://testfate.ru/time').then(function (resp) {
      // getting dateTime fromServer

      var realTime, toMins, diff;

      realTime = moment(resp.data.time).valueOf();
      diff = moment().valueOf() - realTime;

      var beforeStart = moment(value);

      toMins = moment(beforeStart).add(5, 'minutes');

      var toMinsCount = setInterval(function () {
        var now = moment().subtract(diff, 'milliseconds');
        var difference = moment(toMins - now).format('mm:ss');
        if (difference === '00:00') {
          clearInterval(toMinsCount);
        }
        if (now > toMins) {
          clearInterval(toMinsCount);
        } else {
          $(el).find('.short-timer').text(difference);
        }
      }, 1000);

    }, function (err) {
      console.error(err);
    });
  }
```

So what I do is, getting time from server, found difference between local time and server time in ms, then in interval function subtract this difference from local time. Works like a charm for me. My friend suggest this idea to me.

Answer (score 0):

Server and client could have different time, they are not synchronized. Either count with limit of 5 mins every time your server responds or send from your server a limit for countdown, not a server time.

```js
var limit = 5 * 60 // 5 minutes × 60 seconds
  , output = document.getElementById("theFinalCountdown")
  , interval = setInterval(function() {
      if (limit === 0) {
          clearInterval(interval);
      } else {
          output.textContent = // innerText is WRONG, use textContent
              moment.unix(limit).format("mm:ss");
      }
      limit--;
  }, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<div id="theFinalCountdown"></div>
```

Comment: **...or send from your server a limit for countdown** I will try to do this later. But now, is there a way to cut of excess seconds from time I need to add 5 mins. What if convert time in millisecond and calculate if time after adding 5 mins > 05:00 cut excess

Comment: Cutting off excess seconds is simple. Just calculate your date diff object (e. g. resulting in '5:13') and set seconds on that object to zero, like that `moment().seconds(0)`